# Casting value to Float return nil

Tags: swift

coming across an odd problem. I am printing a value in a response as below. In the first print statement it will print the correct value e.g. `Optional(3.0)` however when I cast this value to a Float it becomes nil. The second print statement displays nil. Got no idea on what I'm doing wrong. Any pointers for me? Dictionary like so `userInfoDictionary: [String: Any]?`

```
print("The rating is \(response.userInfoDictionary?[RequestedUserConstant.userRatingKey])")
let userRating = response.userInfoDictionary?[RequestedUserConstant.userRatingKey] as? Float
print("The rating is now \(tutorRating)")
```

Comment: try float ("your value")

Comment: Check once with `as? String` instead of `as? Float`.

Comment: @NiravD also nil...

Comment: It's probably a `Double` instead of a `Float`. What does `print(type(of: response.userInfoDictionary?[RequestedUserConstant.userRatingKey]))` output?

Comment: It is a `Double`, there's a somewhat official explanation [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/issues/48700).

Answer (score 1):

This is because the floating point values are internally Double by default. So the safe way unwrap is **as? Double**.

Example :

```
if let speed = json["averageSpeed"] as? Double {
    //If you need Flot value, simply type cast from Double to Float.
    let floatvalue = Float(speed)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two possible issues:

The first one is, you assign your `response.userInfoDictionary?[RequestedUserConstant.userRatingKey]` to `userRating` but then print the different variable which name is `tutorRating` .

The second one is, it is not a float as @Hamish says so.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of casting it with the `as?` operator try doing it like this: `Float(response.userInfoDictionary?[RequestedUserConstant.userRatingKey])`

Comment: `Float` doesn't have init that accept `Any` as argument.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
let userRating = response.userInfoDictionary?[RequestedUserConstant.userRatingKey].floatValue
```

Comment: **error: value of type 'Any?' has no member 'floatValue'**